# Ubuntu 16.04 - 3 monitor support with Nvidia GeForce GT 710

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, graphics, multiple-monitors

I am looking at purchasing a Nvidia GT 710 for my Ubuntu 16.04 machine so I can connect three monitors.

From Nvidia's specification page (http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-710/specifications) it states that it supports three monitors however I just want to confirm that Ubuntu also supports a multi-monitor setup with this graphics card (as most websites generally forget about the Ubuntu drivers and cater for Windows and OS X in their listings).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally *just* bought a 2gb GeForce 710 and whacked it in my system (replacing a GTS 250 that could only run 2 screens).

Noveau drivers and nVidia drivers will use all three monitors without issue.

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Thanks for that, also replacing a GT 210 for the same issue.

Comment: The 710 is working well for me. Obviously I'm not much of a gamer, and spending the extra on a 750 is no good for me as my cpu would throttle it anyway. But yeah, I'm happy with it so far.

Comment: @RaymondMorgan what resolution did you test? I am interested in stuff handling 2560x1080. I also had GT210 and it worked fine, but I changed my mobo and it complained on lack of GOP on video card and turned off my RAID configuration, so I am looking for something else and GT710 looks like a good replacement.

Comment: I ran 3x monitors using 1920 X 1080p and that ran fine. I can't retest on Ubuntu 18.04 as I've upgraded to a GeForce 1060 since then, but apart from poor gaming performance I had no issues with video and standard applications on the 710.